What is the number of immediates that can be represented ARM data processing instructions?

Data-processing instructions have an unusual immediate representation involving an 8-bit unsigned immediate, imm8, and a 4-bit rotation, rot. imm8 is rotated right by 2 × rot to create a 32-bit constant.
I was wondering about the number of immediates that can be represented in this way and the range of representation

I came up with 3826 different immediates values that space in the range 0-4.278.190.180
Is it right?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about electrical engineering. I'm not sure trivia questions would even  be a good fit on a software site

Actually i saw similar questions in this website

It's an unusual encoding, to be sure.  I get 3073. The odd number is because of the effect of rotating 0.
Here's a map of which values are equal to which lowest imm8 and rot.  You see that every fourth row is a duplicate.  Plus the zero, so the answer is n = (3/4) * 256 * 16 + 1.
It's very difficult to do this by hand or in the head: the best way to get a certain answer is write a small program which which prints things out for you.
        ,0    ,1    ,2    ,3    ,4    ,5    ,6    ,7    ,8    ,9    ,a    ,b    ,c    ,d    ,e    ,f
00:   00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0 =00,0
01:   01,0  01,1  01,2  01,3  01,4  01,5  01,6  01,7  01,8  01,9  01,a  01,b  01,c  01,d  01,e  01,f
02:   02,0  02,1  02,2  02,3  02,4  02,5  02,6  02,7  02,8  02,9  02,a  02,b  02,c  02,d  02,e  02,f
03:   03,0  03,1  03,2  03,3  03,4  03,5  03,6  03,7  03,8  03,9  03,a  03,b  03,c  03,d  03,e  03,f
04:  =01,f =01,0 =01,1 =01,2 =01,3 =01,4 =01,5 =01,6 =01,7 =01,8 =01,9 =01,a =01,b =01,c =01,d =01,e
05:   05,0  05,1  05,2  05,3  05,4  05,5  05,6  05,7  05,8  05,9  05,a  05,b  05,c  05,d  05,e  05,f
06:   06,0  06,1  06,2  06,3  06,4  06,5  06,6  06,7  06,8  06,9  06,a  06,b  06,c  06,d  06,e  06,f
07:   07,0  07,1  07,2  07,3  07,4  07,5  07,6  07,7  07,8  07,9  07,a  07,b  07,c  07,d  07,e  07,f
08:  =02,f =02,0 =02,1 =02,2 =02,3 =02,4 =02,5 =02,6 =02,7 =02,8 =02,9 =02,a =02,b =02,c =02,d =02,e
09:   09,0  09,1  09,2  09,3  09,4  09,5  09,6  09,7  09,8  09,9  09,a  09,b  09,c  09,d  09,e  09,f
0a:   0a,0  0a,1  0a,2  0a,3  0a,4  0a,5  0a,6  0a,7  0a,8  0a,9  0a,a  0a,b  0a,c  0a,d  0a,e  0a,f
0b:   0b,0  0b,1  0b,2  0b,3  0b,4  0b,5  0b,6  0b,7  0b,8  0b,9  0b,a  0b,b  0b,c  0b,d  0b,e  0b,f
0c:  =03,f =03,0 =03,1 =03,2 =03,3 =03,4 =03,5 =03,6 =03,7 =03,8 =03,9 =03,a =03,b =03,c =03,d =03,e
0d:   0d,0  0d,1  0d,2  0d,3  0d,4  0d,5  0d,6  0d,7  0d,8  0d,9  0d,a  0d,b  0d,c  0d,d  0d,e  0d,f
0e:   0e,0  0e,1  0e,2  0e,3  0e,4  0e,5  0e,6  0e,7  0e,8  0e,9  0e,a  0e,b  0e,c  0e,d  0e,e  0e,f
0f:   0f,0  0f,1  0f,2  0f,3  0f,4  0f,5  0f,6  0f,7  0f,8  0f,9  0f,a  0f,b  0f,c  0f,d  0f,e  0f,f
...
fc:  =3f,f =3f,0 =3f,1 =3f,2 =3f,3 =3f,4 =3f,5 =3f,6 =3f,7 =3f,8 =3f,9 =3f,a =3f,b =3f,c =3f,d =3f,e
fd:   fd,0  fd,1  fd,2  fd,3  fd,4  fd,5  fd,6  fd,7  fd,8  fd,9  fd,a  fd,b  fd,c  fd,d  fd,e  fd,f
fe:   fe,0  fe,1  fe,2  fe,3  fe,4  fe,5  fe,6  fe,7  fe,8  fe,9  fe,a  fe,b  fe,c  fe,d  fe,e  fe,f
ff:   ff,0  ff,1  ff,2  ff,3  ff,4  ff,5  ff,6  ff,7  ff,8  ff,9  ff,a  ff,b  ff,c  ff,d  ff,e  ff,f


Very counter-intuitive, because the first thing I did was multiply all the possible numbers with 8 bit excluding the 0 (255 values) by all the possible rotations with 4 bits excluding again the rotation by 0 places (15) to avoid repeating immediates and add the "0" immediate to the result so 255*15+1. I knew there would be duplicates but i don't get why.

I can tell you I got it wrong when I tried to do it in my head!  Repeats: 0x80>>6 == 0x20 >> 4 == 0x08>>2 == 0x02 >> 0 are shifts.
